# Uncaught reference error: AWS not defined

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have been trying to implement DynamoDB using Javascript. When I used, AWS.config.update='my_region', I'm getting "uncaught referenceerror: AWS in not defined". I have declared AWS globally.

Note: aws.sdk.js has been implemented

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `node.js` aws sdk, you should include the `require`.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var creds = new AWS.Credentials('akid', 'secret', 'session');

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
    credentials: creds
});
```

If you are using `JavaScript in HTML`, please include the SDK.

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script>
```

If the above solution doesn't resolve the issue, please show your full code to look at your scenario specifically.

[Javascript Example](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/)

Comment: Hi, Are there any other ways to initiate the AWS namespace? I'm working on Kony(a hybrid MADP) and var AWS = new AWS() doesn't work as it throws a 'not a constructor' error. And there's not a direct way to include it like in the JS script tag anove either. The framework just imports the SDK and stores it in a folder. I'm kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 4):

One Crucial Mistake I was doing is not to add
`<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script>`
 this line in my html code(for front-end side in angular2). If you are using NodeJS then you have to add  this file by using `npm install aws-sdk`.

You can find this information in [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html) link.

Answer (score 1):

I have rectified it. Added the aws-sdk inside head tag instead of adding it in body tag

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/min/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/min/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/min/sjcl.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/src/jsbn.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/src/jsbn2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
AWS.config.update='xx-xxxx-x'; //the aforementioned error(global variable)

var user={
            UserPoolId: 'xx-xxxx-x_xxxxxxxxx', 
            ClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        };

var data=new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(user);       

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({

IdentityPoolId: "xx-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",

});
```